# how to create this procedure from a laravel migration

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, mariadb, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to create this procedure (source: https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/automatic-partition-maintenance-mariadb) from a laravel migration in a Maria database:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE db1.create_new_partitions(p_schema varchar(64), p_table varchar(64), p_months_to_add int)
   LANGUAGE SQL
   NOT DETERMINISTIC
   SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN  
   DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
   DECLARE current_partition_name varchar(64);
   DECLARE current_partition_ts int;

   -- We'll use this cursor later to check
   -- whether a particular already exists.
   -- @partition_name_to_add will be
   -- set later.
   DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR 
   SELECT partition_name 
   FROM information_schema.partitions 
   WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = p_schema 
   AND TABLE_NAME = p_table 
   AND PARTITION_NAME != 'p_first'
   AND PARTITION_NAME != 'p_future'
   AND PARTITION_NAME = @partition_name_to_add;

   -- We'll also use this cursor later 
   -- to query our temporary table.
   DECLARE cur2 CURSOR FOR 
   SELECT partition_name, partition_range_ts 
   FROM partitions_to_add;

   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

   DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS partitions_to_add;

   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE partitions_to_add (
      partition_name varchar(64),
      partition_range_ts int
   );

   SET @partitions_added = FALSE;
   SET @months_ahead = 0;

   -- Let's go through a loop and add each month individually between
   -- the current month and the month p_months_to_add in the future.
   WHILE @months_ahead <= p_months_to_add DO
      -- We figure out what the correct month is by adding the
      -- number of months to the current date
      SET @date = CURDATE();
      SET @q = 'SELECT DATE_ADD(?, INTERVAL ? MONTH) INTO @month_to_add';
      PREPARE st FROM @q;
      EXECUTE st USING @date, @months_ahead;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE st;
      SET @months_ahead = @months_ahead + 1;

      -- Then we format the month in the same format used
      -- in our partition names.
      SET @q = 'SELECT DATE_FORMAT(@month_to_add, ''%Y%m'') INTO @formatted_month_to_add';
      PREPARE st FROM @q;
      EXECUTE st;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE st;

      -- And then we use the formatted date to build the name of the
      -- partition that we want to add. This partition name is
      -- assigned to @partition_name_to_add, which is used in
      -- the cursor declared at the start of the procedure.
      SET @q = 'SELECT CONCAT(''p'', @formatted_month_to_add) INTO @partition_name_to_add';
      PREPARE st FROM @q;
      EXECUTE st;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE st;

      SET done = FALSE; 
      SET @first = TRUE;

      -- And then we loop through the results returned by the cursor,
      -- and if a row already exists for the current partition, 
      -- then we do not need to create the partition.
      OPEN cur1;

      read_loop: LOOP
         FETCH cur1 INTO current_partition_name;

         -- The cursor returned 0 rows, so we can create the partition.
         IF done AND @first THEN
            SELECT CONCAT('Creating partition: ', @partition_name_to_add);

            -- Now we need to get the end date of the new partition.
            -- Note that the date is for the non-inclusive end range,
            -- so we actually need the date of the first day of the *next* month.

            -- First, let's get a date variable for the first of the partition month
            SET @q = 'SELECT DATE_FORMAT(@month_to_add, ''%Y-%m-01 00:00:00'') INTO @month_to_add';
            PREPARE st FROM @q;
            EXECUTE st;
            DEALLOCATE PREPARE st; 

            -- Then, let's add 1 month
            SET @q = 'SELECT DATE_ADD(?, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) INTO @partition_end_date';
            PREPARE st FROM @q;
            EXECUTE st USING @month_to_add;
            DEALLOCATE PREPARE st;

            -- We need the date in UNIX timestamp format.  
            SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@partition_end_date) INTO @partition_end_ts;

            -- Now insert the information into our temporary table
            INSERT INTO partitions_to_add VALUES (@partition_name_to_add, @partition_end_ts);
            SET @partitions_added = TRUE;
         END IF;

         -- Since we had at least one row returned, we know the
         -- partition already exists.
         IF ! @first THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
         END IF;

         SET @first = FALSE;
      END LOOP;

     CLOSE cur1;
   END WHILE;

   -- Let's actually add the partitions now.
   IF @partitions_added THEN
      -- First we need to build the actual ALTER TABLE query.
      SET @schema = p_schema;
      SET @table = p_table;
      SET @q = 'SELECT CONCAT(''ALTER TABLE '', @schema, ''.'', @table, '' REORGANIZE PARTITION p_future INTO ( '') INTO @query';
      PREPARE st FROM @q;
      EXECUTE st;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE st;

      SET done = FALSE;
      SET @first = TRUE;

      OPEN cur2;

      read_loop: LOOP
         FETCH cur2 INTO current_partition_name, current_partition_ts;

        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
         END IF;

         -- If it is not the first partition, 
         -- then we need to add a comma
         IF ! @first THEN
            SET @q = 'SELECT CONCAT(@query, '', '') INTO @query';
            PREPARE st FROM @q;
            EXECUTE st;
            DEALLOCATE PREPARE st;
         END IF;

         -- Add the current partition
         SET @partition_name =  current_partition_name;
         SET @partition_ts =  current_partition_ts;         
         SET @q = 'SELECT CONCAT(@query, ''PARTITION '', @partition_name, '' VALUES LESS THAN ('', @partition_ts, '')'') INTO @query';
         PREPARE st FROM @q;
         EXECUTE st;
         DEALLOCATE PREPARE st;

         SET @first = FALSE;
      END LOOP;

      CLOSE cur2;

      -- We also need to include the p_future partition
      SET @q = 'SELECT CONCAT(@query, '', PARTITION p_future VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE))'') INTO @query';
      PREPARE st FROM @q;
      EXECUTE st;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE st;

      -- And then we prepare and execute the ALTER TABLE query.
      PREPARE st FROM @query;
      EXECUTE st;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE st;  
   END IF;

   DROP TEMPORARY TABLE partitions_to_add;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I use heredoc to set the variable:

```
    $createTableProcedure = <<<SQL
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE ...
    END
$$
DELIMITER ;
SQL;
    DB::unprepared($createTableProcedure);
```

This code works fine from console or in my case SequelPro. Yet laravel returns a MariaDB syntax error.
This answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/18393771/928666) to a similar problem states:

> DELIMITER is not a valid sql statement. It's just a MySql client command. So just don't use it.

Okay so I stripped the DELIMITER change but now I get a syntax error at line 6 which is the first DECLARE statement after BEGIN:

`DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;`

Also for this I found a stack (https://stackoverflow.com/a/36158005/928666) which states:

> You are missing the delimiter definition before and after the stored proc definition

So now I happily end in a loop. Whatever I do I end up with a syntax error.

So how can I create that procedure from a laravel migration?

Comment: Is it mandatory for you that the stored procedure is created with laravel? Or would it also be acceptable if you create the sp in the database and call this sp from laravel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a stored procedure in Laravel like this, this will render the `DELIMITER` obsolete:

```
$procedure = "
    CREATE PROCEDURE `your_new_procedure`(procedure_param_1 TEXT, procedure_param_2 INT)
    BEGIN
         // Your SP here
    END
";

DB::unprepared("DROP procedure IF EXISTS your_new_procedure");
DB::unprepared($procedure);
```

And to call it:

```
DB:raw(
'call your_new_procedure(?, ?),
[
    $var2,
    $var2,
]
);
```

Source:   Stored Procedures in Laravel
https://medium.com/@smayzes/stored-procedures-in-laravel-60e7cb255fc9

Comment: The problem was I used heredoc and with this it didn't work.